How to deal with opposite numbering of connectors
I use an FFC cable to connect a display to my board.
The connector on the display has its pinout well defined.
Also the connector on my PCB has clearly indicated which is pin 1.
Under ideal conditions all should be coherent, pin 1 of the display should be connected to pin 1 on the connector on my PCB.
Since the PCB and display are placed back-to-back it happens the numbering of my connector should be reversed: pin 1 should be placed on the right side (looking at the datasheet).
I see two possible ways to handle this situation:

leave the correct pinout on the FFC connector and reverse the schematic assignment (i.e. Vdd of the display is now connected to pin 20 instead of pin 1). The downside is now the schematic is not easily readable (since to follow the signals going to the display you have to calculate 20 - N)

leave the correct assignment of the signals (in order to solve the above problem) but create a new component of the connector reversing the pinout. I also don't like this solution because the connector itself has the indication of pin 1 and it would be incorrect


I'm not asking an opinion. I'm asking what is the recommended way to clear design a board with these costraints. I guess it's a common problem but I was not able to find an answer looking at other questions or on the Internet.

isn't it just a matter of changing the silkscreen?

@jsotola if I change the silkscreen (i.e. pin #1 on the opposite side of the FFC connector) it does not match anymore the datasheet and the indication on the connector itself

The answer is "very carefully" and "with lots of double-checking".

I want to challenge the premise: "Under ideal conditions all should be coherent, pin 1 of the display should be connected to pin 1 on the connector on my PCB.". || Try making boards meant to be stacked using male/female smt headers, passing signals through the board. You have to flip, either through X or Y axis. (Or maybe have symbols with "board bottom" numbering and "board top" numbering. Both ways requires "very carefully" and "with lots of double-checking")

FFCs are a pain in this regard. If you use the same style of connector at each end, the pin 1's are at opposite sides of the cable. Unlike a ribbon cable, an FFC cable has no notion of 'pin 1'.
As a board designer, the best you can do is follow the connector marking for pin 1 and put it on the silkscreen. Then at the system level, you triple-check that the signal sequence at each connector pair is mirrored correctly. Do a cable drawing if you have to.
In your case you're sourcing a panel that has a defined pinout. Your controller pinout should be mirrored. Again, it's just something you need to check.
Should you (or your co-worker, supplier, etc.) be unlucky enough to get it wrong, you have a couple of options for bring up:

Use a 'flip' cable (conductors on opposite sides) and twist the cable. This is probably the easiest option.
Mount one of the connectors in the opposite direction (rotate 180)
Use a vertical style and mount in the opposite direction (again, rotate 180) - works if there isn't room.

Using one of these strategies will buy you some time while you fix your layout.

From my experience, the pin numbers need to be consistent between plug (the movable part of the connection) and jack (the fixed part of the connection).  That is SIG_A comes out of the board on pin 1, and goes into the backplane or cable connector on pin 1.  Similarly for all the other signals.
This means that the physical location of pin 1 (and all other pins) need to be mirrored between the plug and jack.
This helps immensely when designing a backplane with multiple boards plugged into it, because it means that the net list for the board(s) that contains the IO connector can just be imported into the net list for the backplane, with no translation required.

I agree but in this case I have to twist the FFC cable by 180 degrees to keep the pinouts consistent
